# Set fancybox-skin to fixed size and center all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

Im using fancybox `version: 2.1.3` and what im trying to do is :

1. **Set the width and height to 600px x 400px fixed.**
2. **If image is smaller than popup box make it center and dont resize.**

For now this is my current setting :

index.html

```
$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
    minWidth: 600,
    maxWidth: 600,
    minHeight: 400,
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    autoScale : false,
    fitToView : false,
```

jquery.fancybox.js

```
$.extend(F, {
// The current version of fancyBox
version: '2.1.3',

defaults: {
padding : 15,
margin  : 20,

width     : 600,
height    : 400,

minWidth  : 600,
minHeight : 400,

maxWidth  : 600,
maxHeight : 400,

autoSize   : false,
autoHeight : false,
autoWidth  : false,

autoResize  : false,
autoCenter  : !isTouch,
fitToView   : false,
aspectRatio : false,
```

and the result is something like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQfQ.jpg but when i click next https://i.stack.imgur.com/xReHC.jpg .. you can see the size is not fixed that is the main problem ..

what i want if image is smaller the popup and image size should be like this [image]

*P/s : this is first time i try to modified fancybox maybe its a bit confusing for me.*

Answer (score 0):

I have "ugly way", but i do not have more time search for a suitable combination of options.
And so, adding jquery-options:

```
    fitToView : false,
    wrapCSS: 'myclass'
```

and add styles:

```
    .myclass, 
    .myclass .fancybox-skin 
    {
        width: 600px !important;
        height: 400px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .myclass .fancybox-skin 
    {
        line-height: 400px;
    }
    .myclass .fancybox-outer {
        height: inherit;
        width: inherit;
    }
    .myclass .fancybox-inner {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```